# how can give arrow key events in full page image silder

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

How can give arrow key events in full page image slider, for example the below sample link -> https://www.htmllion.com/examples/pure-css-based-fullscreen-slider-demo.html.
I need the same layout with  arrow key events.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

Use Keyboard [events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/) in Jquery. Based on the user click navigate the page

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can do something like this.

```
$(window).on('keyup', function(e){
    console.log(e.keyCode); // log the keycode of the key pressed
    switch(e.keyCode){
        case 37:
            console.log('Prev');
            break;
        case 38:
            console.log('Up');
            break;
        case 39:
            console.log('Next');
            break;
        case 40:
            console.log('Down');
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a keydown event to any element and call a function.
In the below example i have used an input text field to add a keydown event and it gives alert on pressing left or right arrow key

```js
function myFunction(event) {
    var keyVal = event.keyCode;
    
    switch(keyVal)
    {
      case 37:
      alert('Pressed left');
      break;
      case 39:
      alert('Pressed right');
      break;
    }
   
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="myFunction(event)">
```